# Swift: Update Parse User (PFUser) and save image to it after new registration

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, back4app

I have been banging my head since yesterday. I have fetch profile picture from facebook and want to save it to parse. But I am stuck. I tried solution from this

[How to update Parse user information in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775612/how-to-update-parse-user-information-in-swift)

That did not solved my case.

[Updating user in Parse.com using Swift IOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338037/updating-user-in-parse-com-using-swift-ios8)

I dont think this is  the case, since I have just logged in. and my view changes too.

here's my code.

```
func updateCurrentUserProfilePicture(image: UIImage) {
        let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
        let id = currentUser?.objectId
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        var query = PFUser.query()

        query!.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(id!) {
            (user: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else if let usr = user {
                // usr.setObject(data!, forKey: "image")
                usr["image"] = data!
                usr.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (result: Bool, error: NSError?) in
                    if error == nil {
                            self.delegate?.didUpdateProfilePictureWithResult!(true, error: error)
                    }else {
                        self.delegate?.didUpdateProfilePictureWithResult!(false, error: error)
                    }

                })
            }
        }
    }
```

I can see that `didUpdateProfilePictureWithResult` delegate is called with success. But when I go to back4app.com, I can see the `user` row but not the `image` column. And I dont see any error too.

What am I missing here?

**Update**
I tried to save in in the console. It saved without any error.

```
**expression do { try usr.save()} catch { print(error)}**
2016-06-10 17:29:32.264 GeofenceMe2[39334:91037] Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
NilError
```

but still no image column in my dashboaard

Comment: there is no `usr` variable decleration in your code. where does it come from

Comment: else if let usr = user   there is

Comment: sorry my bad. try logging in the user in the console right in the code and see if it has the image property

Comment: I can see usr as '(PFUser) $R0 = 0x7ae5b9d0 {
  PFObject = { .... ' in debugger

Comment: well. when i put debugger in third line, i can see the image is there.  expression image
(UIImage) $R1 = 0x79e44560 {
  ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot save `NSData` to parse. Checkout the valid data types here: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-data-types.

You are querying for the user object using the same user object. You can just use PFUser.currentUser().

```
func updateCurrentUserProfilePicture(image: UIImage) {
    let avatar = PFFile(name: PFUser.currentUser()!.username, data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!)
    PFUser.currentUser()!.setObject(avatar!, forKey: "avatar")
    PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) in

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5.x (based in above answer by @Santhosh):

```
func updateCurrentUserProfilePicture(profileImage: UIImage) {

    guard let currentUser = PFUser.current(), let profileImgPngData = profileImage.pngData() else {
            return
    }

    let avatar = PFFileObject(name: PFUser.current()!.username, data: profileImgPngData)

    currentUser.setObject(avatar!, forKey: "profile_image")
    currentUser.saveInBackground { success, error in
        print(success, error as Any)
    }
}
```